# C++ Unit Test in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, unit-testing, oop, visual-studio-2019

I am having a problem with Visual Studio 2019 CPPUnitTestFramework. I follow the instructions, but every time I get an error. I have looked for tutorials, but anything I get is for Visual Studio 2017 and it does not solve my problem.

I am writing a program that uses OOP in C++ and I want to make unit tests, since it is going to be a considerably long project. The problem that I am having is that the program is not compiling in the test module.

Consider that I have the code such that I have the header file:

```
//A.h
#pragma once
class A
{
private:
   // One parameter.
   int a;

public:

   // Add function.
   int add(int, int);

   // Subtract function.
   int subtract(int, int);

   A();
};
```

with the proper source file:

```
// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
int a;

int A::add(int alpha, int beta)
{
    return alpha + beta;
}

int A::subtract(int alpha, int beta)
{
    return alpha - beta;
}

A::A()
{
    a = 4;
}
```

The structure of the program looks something like this:

[image]

To make my Unit Test, I right click on the "Solution 'TestTestUnit'" label and choose new project, look for the unit test, add the unit test and attach the reference, such that I get a file structure such as the one below:

[image]

To perform the unit test I write the code:

```
// TestUnitForTestTestUnit.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

#include "../TestTestUnit/A.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace TestUnitForTestTestUnit
{
   TEST_CLASS(TestUnitForTestTestUnit)
   {
   public:
    
      TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
      {
         A first;
         Assert::AreEqual(first.add(3, 2), 5);
      }
   };
}
```

When I try to run a test, the Test Explorer does nothing and throws the message: **Aborting test run due to build failures. Please see the build for more details.**

[image]

I cannot find the mistake here. The program runs perfect, but when instantiating a new "A" object the test fails. I am stuck here, are there any suggestions? What am I doing wrong (besides developing in Windows)?

**UPDATE**:

I have followed the suggestion to remove the namespace, as suggested by @ChrisMM, so that the test file now reads:

```
// TestUnitForTestTestUnit.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

#include "../TestTestUnit/A.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

TEST_CLASS(TestUnitForTestTestUnit)
{
public:
    
   TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
   {
      A first;
      Assert::AreEqual(first.add(3, 2), 5);
   }
};
```

such that when I run the Test Explorer gives the same message:

[image]

with error message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestUnitForTestTestUnit, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>   Creating library C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\CPlusPlus\TestTestUnit\Debug\TestUnitForTestTestUnit.lib and object C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\CPlusPlus\TestTestUnit\Debug\TestUnitForTestTestUnit.exp
1>TestUnitForTestTestUnit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall A::add(int,int)" (?add@A@@QAEHHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TestUnitForTestTestUnit::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@TestUnitForTestTestUnit@@QAEXXZ)
1>TestUnitForTestTestUnit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall A::A(void)" (??0A@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TestUnitForTestTestUnit::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@TestUnitForTestTestUnit@@QAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\CPlusPlus\TestTestUnit\Debug\TestUnitForTestTestUnit.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "TestUnitForTestTestUnit.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to check if TestUnitForTestTestUnit has added `Additional Dependencies`. When I didn’t add it, the same problem as you occurred. After I added it, the program worked fine.

Right click `TestUnitForTestTestUnit`->Properties->C/C++->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies-> add `..\TestTestUnit\Debug\*.obj`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! I cannot stress enough how thankful I am for the answer. MS should up their game in their tutorials and documentation, terrible in the current state!

Comment: That is very strange idea to add `*.obj` files as additional dependencies for the linker. Probably the external sources should be built as a static/dynamic library? There is also a Shared Items Project in VisualStudio, which just collects source files for further inclusion in other projects.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put a test class inside a namespace. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#create_test_classes_and_methods)

> `TEST_CLASS` must be declared at namespace scope.

Comment: Hi, if you could please provide a better example it would be appreciated. As I have already pointed out, I have already tried everything in the links inside the link you have provided. Even defining both test and source+header files in the same namespace (I might be doing it wrong). Much appreciated.

Comment: @AGEscovar, There is no example to provide. You simply cannot put the test class inside a namespace. Your's is inside `TestUnitForTestTestUnit`, simply get rid of the namespace.

Comment: I have done so, several times, and it still throws the same error. I have no idea what to further do.

Comment: @AGEscovar, test explorer cannot find any tests because it fails to build. If you've already removed the namespace, then you need to provide the errors.

Comment: I have just updated the post with the error message once I take the namespace out. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: note that official MS examples occasionally place tests inside namespaces - see [Write the unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-cpp-dlls?view=vs-2022#addTests). And according to MS (see [Scope (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170)), visibility in a **namescape scope** is when a name _is declared within a namespace, outside of any class or enum definition or function block, is visible from its point of declaration to the end of the namespace_

Answer (score 0):

Try to include .cpp file, but not .h
I used to include headers, but I had build errors. With .cpp everything works fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).